# Find the indices and values that larger than a threshold in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have a matrix and I want to find the indices and values that larger than a threshold，so how to do it with CUDA? Or it's a better way to copy the matrix to memory and let cpu do the work?

Comment: I am wondering if there is a better way out there that I haven't figure out

Comment: A better way than what? You haven't explained anything about what you are using or trying to do now.

Comment: Read the question again if you don't know what I am trying, thanks

Comment: what kind of matrix? 1D, 2D, ... ? how do you store them, linearly?

Comment: It's 2D matrix, linearly stored, but does this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this very easily using [Thrust](http://thrust.github.io/), which offers you the basic building blocks you need. The following code first finds the indices which fulfill the condition (`value > threshold`) and then extracts the corresponding values. If you don't need the indices, you can do all this in one step.

```
#include <thrust/gather.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

int main()
{
  const int N = 100;
  int threshold = 90;

  thrust::device_vector<int> data(N);
  // fill with demo data
  thrust::sequence(data.begin(), data.end());

  // find out the indices
  thrust::device_vector<int> indices(N);
  thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator end = thrust::copy_if(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
                                                             thrust::make_counting_iterator(N),
                                                             data.begin(),
                                                             indices.begin(), 
                                                             thrust::placeholders::_1 > threshold);
  int size = end-indices.begin();
  indices.resize(size);

  // fetch corresponding values
  thrust::device_vector<int> values(size);
  thrust::copy(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(data.begin(), indices.begin()),
               thrust::make_permutation_iterator(data.end(), indices.end()),
               values.begin());

  std::cout << "indices: ";
  thrust::copy(indices.begin(), indices.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << "values: ";
  thrust::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output of this demo program is:

```
indices: 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
values: 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Comment: Could you please explain this line: `thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator end ...` ?

Comment: @JithinPavithran what exactly is unclear? as I wrote in the answer, this  finds the indices which fulfill the condition `(value > threshold)`

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is a build-in function to do this in thrust:

[ForwardIterator thrust::lower_bound  (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const LessThanComparable& value)](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__binary__search_ga1e475b6887f3dcbbb1bc0f68225d0cac.html#ga1e475b6887f3dcbbb1bc0f68225d0cac)

It returns the iterator to the first element where value could be inserted while maintaining the ordering of the list. So if value is your threshold, it will return the iterator to the first element i for which threshold >= i.

Thanks for the downvote, I will probably not attempt again to answer a question.

Comment: That would only satisfy the question if the sequence was sorted

Comment: Fortunately Thrust has you covered on sorting. [https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__sorting.html](thrust::sort)